# Lifetimes in Rust when using Strings

Tags: rust

I have been experimenting on Rust for quite some time. There is a confusion regarding the lifetimes in Rust.Have a look in the code below:

```rust
fn main() {
    let string1 = String::from("abcd");
    let result;
    {
        let string2 = "xyzvn";

        result = longest(string1.as_str(), string2);
    }
    println!("The Longest String is {}", result);
}

fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

`string2`s lifetime ends after the inner scope, and result is defined in the outer scope. When passing the result to `println!`, the compiler does not complain, and goes ahead and prints the result.

However when I change `string2` to be a `String`:

```rust
let string2 = String::from("xyzvd");
```

The borrow checker will complain. Why is that happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type for a string literal `”xyzvn”` is `&'static str` which means it lives as long as the program does. But when you create a new string based on it its lifetime ends at the end of the block and it cannot be used outside.

For more information see the [documentation on static lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-static-lifetime)